# gridview Validation is triggered in emptydatatemplate when entry is valid

Tags: asp.net, validation, gridview

I have a Gridview that has 3 columns, ID, Text, Action.  I am using VS2010. When the grid is empty and the user enters text in the text field, I would like the field to be validated as a required field and a max. length.  These validations work fine if there is data in the grid but when the grid is empty, the required validation is triggered after the user enters data.  If the user enters a second time, the data is successfully added to the database and refreshed in the grid.

Secondly, the column headers will not show when the grid is empty even though I had the attribute: ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" 
This is my markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="SubjectInfoGridView" runat="server" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="false" Caption="Personal Subject List" 
        CaptionAlign="Top" CssClass="grid"
        RowStyle-Wrap="true" HorizontalAlign="Left" ShowFooter="true" 
        AllowPaging="false" PageSize="5" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" 
        onrowcancelingedit="SubjectInfoGridView_RowCancelingEdit" 
        onrowediting="SubjectInfoGridView_RowEditing" 
        onrowdeleting="SubjectInfoGridView_RowDeleting" 
        onrowcommand="SubjectInfoGridView_RowCommand" 
        onrowupdating="SubjectInfoGridView_RowUpdating">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Subject ID">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="sigvLblSubjectID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SubjectID") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField>
             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Subject" ItemStyle-Wrap="false"> 
             <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="sigvLblSubject" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Subject") %>'></asp:Label>
             </ItemTemplate>
             <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="sigvTxtBoxEditSubject" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Subject") %>'></asp:TextBox>      
                     <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldEditSubject" ControlToValidate="sigvTxtBoxEditSubject" runat="server"
                        ErrorMessage="Required field." ValidationGroup="EditSubjectValidation" Display="Dynamic" CssClass="message-error">
                    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>            
                     <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="MaxValEditSubject" ControlToValidate="sigvTxtBoxEditSubject" runat="server"
                        ErrorMessage="Maximumn length is 80." ValidationGroup="EditSubjectValidation" Display="Dynamic" CssClass="message-error"
                        ValidationExpression="^.{1,80}$" >
                    </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
             </EditItemTemplate>
             <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="sigvTxtBoxInsertSubject" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Subject") %>'></asp:TextBox>      
                     <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldInsertSubject" ControlToValidate="sigvTxtBoxInsertSubject" runat="server"
                        ErrorMessage="Required field." ValidationGroup="InsertSubjectValidation" Display="Dynamic" CssClass="message-error">
                    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>            
                     <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="MaxValInsertSubject" ControlToValidate="sigvTxtBoxInsertSubject" runat="server"
                        ErrorMessage="Maximumn length is 80." ValidationGroup="InsertSubjectValidation" Display="Dynamic" CssClass="message-error"
                        ValidationExpression="^.{1,80}$" >
                    </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
             </FooterTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField>
             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                 <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="sigvEditButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit" 
                                Text="Edit" CssClass="gridActionbutton">
                    </asp:Button>
                    &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="sigvDeleteButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Delete" 
                                Text="Delete" CssClass="gridActionbutton"  OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this Device Information?')" >
                    </asp:Button>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="sigvUpdateButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" ValidationGroup="EditSubjectValidation" CommandName="Update" 
                                    Text="Update" CssClass="gridActionbutton"></asp:Button>
                    &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="sigvCancelButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" 
                                    Text="Cancel" CssClass="gridActionbutton"></asp:Button>
                </EditItemTemplate>                  
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="sigvAddButton" runat="server" CommandName="Add" Text="Add Subject" Width="90%" CausesValidation="true" 
                                CssClass="gridActionbutton" ValidationGroup="InsertSubjectValidation">
                    </asp:Button>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
       </Columns>
       <EmptyDataTemplate>
        <tr> 
            <td colspan="3" style="text-align:center;">
                No User-defined Subjects were found for you. Subjects can be added by clicking the 'Add Subject' Button.
            </td> 
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="sigvTxtBoxInsertSubject" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Subject") %>' Width="90%"></asp:TextBox>      
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldInsertSubjectEmpty" ControlToValidate="sigvTxtBoxInsertSubject" runat="server"
                        ErrorMessage="Required field." ValidationGroup="InsertSubjectValidation" Display="Dynamic" CssClass="message-error">
                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>            
                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="MaxValInsertSubjectEmpty" ControlToValidate="sigvTxtBoxInsertSubject" runat="server"
                        ErrorMessage="Maximumn length is 80." ValidationGroup="InsertSubjectValidation" Display="Dynamic" CssClass="message-error"
                        ValidationExpression="^.{1,80}$" >
                </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>              
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="sigvAddButtonEmpty" runat="server" CommandName="Add" Text="Add Subject" Width="90%" CausesValidation="true" 
                        CssClass="gridActionbutton" ValidationGroup="InsertSubjectValidation">
                </asp:Button>
            </td>
        </tr>
       </EmptyDataTemplate>
    </asp:GridView>
```

So, why won't the headers show when the grid is empty and what am I doing wrong with the validation that triggers the RequiredValidation after data is entered in the field?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**
I solved the 'Header problem' but just adding them to the EmptyDataTemplate. But the validation is still a problem. 
I did this using VS2012 at another company and it was not a problem. I tried making the TextBox id different than the Insert ID and it still gives the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out...
In case anybody else has this problem.
To correct the validation, I removed the text binding (Text='<%# Bind("Subject") %>').  Then I changed the ID for the Subject field to the same as in the Footer when I add a row when there is data. This allows me to only check one control within the RowBound event.
This is the data row in the EmptyDataTemplate:

```
<tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="sigvTxtBoxInsertSubject" runat="server" Width="90%"></asp:TextBox>      
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldInsertSubjectEmpty" ControlToValidate="sigvTxtBoxInsertSubject" runat="server"
                        ErrorMessage="Required field." ValidationGroup="InsertSubjectValidationEmpty" Display="Dynamic" CssClass="message-error">
                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>            
                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="MaxValInsertSubjectEmpty" ControlToValidate="sigvTxtBoxInsertSubject" runat="server"
                        ErrorMessage="Maximumn length is 80." ValidationGroup="InsertSubjectValidationEmpty" Display="Dynamic" CssClass="message-error"
                        ValidationExpression="^.{1,80}$" >
                </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>                              
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="sigvAddButtonEmpty" runat="server" CommandName="Add" Text="Add Subject" Width="90%" CausesValidation="true" 
                        CssClass="gridActionbutton" ValidationGroup="InsertSubjectValidationEmpty" >
                </asp:Button>
            </td>
        </tr>
```